# Macros to show page number on the right side of the footer

Tags: macros, page-numbering, footer

I want to show page number on the right side of the footer.

Currently, it's shown in the center of the footer.

This is my macros:

```
% Macros to format the page numbering.
\def\ps@myheadings{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
                   \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\thepage}
           %\def\@oddfoot{}
                   \def\@evenfoot{\hfil\thepage}
           %\def\@evenfoot{}
                   \def\sectionmark##1{}
           \def\subsectionmark##1{}
}
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Oh my, yesterday you asked about pushing the number from the right to the center, now back to the right footer?  Have a look into the fancyhdr package

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Assuming that you are using it correctly, your code should work and your problem is probably only with the first page of a chapter etc.

Comment: But to answer your question, change \hfil to \hfill.  \hfil and \parfillskip (end of line) expand equally, but \hfill overwhelms \parfillskip.

Comment: Packages like `fancyhdr`, `scrlayer-scrpage` or `titleps` can help you. You are working at a low level, a level you don't have enough experience yet.